# Django:Reverse for 'Search' not found. 'Search' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django

I am. trying to. build a search function for my django project base on the [enter link description here](https://pytutorial.com/django-search-function)

and the error message popped out "Reverse for 'Search' not found. 'Search' is not a valid view function or pattern name."

i have done the searching most of the advise asking me to check if the spelling is error

like my "search" in url or my search.html in my render

however, i have tried all the solution it still can't work

here is some of my code

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from pages.views import home_view, contact_view, about_view
from products.views import product_detail_view, product_create_view, vendor_data,search_product

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home_view, name='home'),
    path('contact/', contact_view),
    path('about/', about_view),
    path('create/', product_create_view),
    path('product/', product_detail_view),
    path('search/', search_product),
    path('vendor/', vendor_data),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Product

from .forms import ProductForm, RawProductForm,VendorForm


def search_product(request):
    if  request.method == "POST":
        query_name = request.POST.get('title', None)
        if query_name:
            results = Product.objects.filter(name__contains=query_name)
            return render(request, 'products/search.html', {"results":results})

    return render(request, 'products/search.html')
```

search.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Django Search</title>
</head>
<body>



<form action="{% url 'search' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %} 
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
</form>



{% for result in results %}

    <p>{{result.name}}</p>

{% endfor %}

</body>
</html>
```

and following is my folder in case if needed

[image]

Comment: Please share your `urls.py`.

Comment: Please share proper urls.py

Comment: omg let me fix it didn't notice it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this file.. `urls.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from pages.views import home_view, contact_view, about_view
from products.views import product_detail_view, product_create_view, vendor_data,search_product

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home_view, name='home'),
    path('contact/', contact_view),
    path('about/', about_view),
    path('create/', product_create_view),
    path('product/', product_detail_view),
    path('search/', search_product, name = 'search'), # changed here
    path('vendor/', vendor_data),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

]
```

Comment: however i still don't know how it actually works , is there something i need to learn in case of some situation happen in the future?

Comment: You should use the name parameter for all kinds of URLs, so that it will be easy to write that  URL in HTML Template either you should write the absolute URL at all times and even it will be very helpful for production environments.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the name of the `urls.py` with the `name=…` parameter:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # …,
    #                              name ↓
    path('search/', search_product, name='search'),
    # …
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Encountering a similar issue while adding new features to my Django project during the testing phase

```
Reverse for 'detail' not found. 'detail' is not a valid view function or 
pattern name.
```

I found out that when I call reverse("detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk}) in my get_absolute_url() method, Django will look for a URL pattern with the name "detail" and substitute the value of self.pk into the URL pattern to generate the absolute URL for that particular instance of the Course model.

Without defining name='detail' in my urls.py, Django wouldn't have a named URL pattern to associate with the identifier "detail." Consequently, when attempting to use reverse("detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk}) in my get_absolute_url() method, Django would be unable to locate the appropriate URL pattern, leading to the error message: "Reverse for 'detail' not found."

```
path('<int:pk>',views.CourseDetailView.as_view(),name='detail'),
```